# Visual Basic C++ and Visual Studio Install Problems

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, visual-studio, visual-basic

my PC has some problems. When I install Visual Studio or Visual Basic, I have to kill dllhost (First problem) to bypass system restore, as I corrupted system restore and pretty much the whole WindowsRE partition. Second problem, the installer tries to run a seperate "Minimum Runtime" program in a temp directory, which freezes infinitely (Second Problem). This has been bugging me since the dawn of time (When I wiped my disk and installed using an ISO). *Help?*

Comment: Still working on reproducing a log file.

Comment: in system properties, disable system restore completely and delete all restore points. now activate it again and try to create a restore point

Comment: Yeah, here's the thing. SYSTEM RESTORE IS COMPLETE BLANK. IT JUST SAYS SEARCHING FOR DRIVES.

Comment: can yo start the VSS service via services.msc?

Comment: Yes, volume shadow copy is set to auto.